# Oracle Trigger - Condition before insert

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I don't know what my problem when created new trigger. 
Is my syntax correct? Thanks! [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0HkR.png) [Logging pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE0hq.png)

p/s: This my console display when I try to insert values

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EX03_3 
BEFORE INSERT ON HR.CHITIETDATHANG
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    TONGHANG NUMBER; -- Total Items  
    HANGHIENCO NUMBER; -- Items present
    HANGDABAN NUMBER; -- Items was sales.
BEGIN
    -- Get total Items
    SELECT SUM(MH.SOLUONG) INTO TONGHANG
    FROM HR.MATHANG MH;

    -- Get total Items was sales
    SELECT SUM(CTDH.SOLUONG) INTO HANGDABAN
    FROM HR.CHITIETDATHANG CTDH;
    
    -- Items present
    HANGHIENCO := TONGHANG - HANGDABAN;
    
    IF(HANGHIENCO >= HANGDABAN) THEN
        HANGHIENCO := HANGHIENCO-1;
        INSERT INTO HR.CHITIETDATHANG VALUES(:NEW.SOHOADON,:NEW.MAHANG,
            :NEW.GIABAN,:NEW.SOLUONG,:NEW.MUCGIAMGIA);
        ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
  NULL;
END;
```

Comment: The trigger for which error is thrown is `EX04_4` , but the one shown here is `EX03_3` ..?

Comment: What logic are you trying to implement? Your trigger does a calculation but what do you want to happen as a result?

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do, but I think there are issues with the way you're implementing triggers. Triggers cannot have commit or rollback (unless autonomous) and not sure why you'd insert into the same table from a trigger on a table. You might want to consider a view and use of "instead of insert" if you need to decide to insert or not to insert into a table using triggers.   Also, getting summation from other tables can have implications: you won't have a consistent snapshot for the two selects, and you might get into issues of locking unless proper indexing of foreign keys

Comment: Agreed with Baha's comments; plus: it very rarely makes sense to query the tables with no WHERE clause in a context like this - it makes it look like this is a single-user, single-transaction database, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seem two critical mistakes

1) trigger tries to insert into `HR.CHITIETDATHANG` in the body of insert trigger of `HR.CHITIETDATHANG`.

2) to use `rollback` after an insert statement is useless.

Note : I can see nothing relevant to make raise no_data_found in those select statements. EX03_3 and EX04_4 are confused, as Kaushik Nayak says.